# Pre select option item from the list in ngFor

Tags: angular

The value of currently selected option is in `userDetail.timezone`
This doesn't work

```
<option selected="userDetail.timezone" value="{{timezone.value}}" *ngFor="let timezone of timezones.success">`
```

..

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="timezone" name="timezone" *ngIf="timezones">
            <option value="{{timezone.value}}" *ngFor="let timezone of timezones.success">
              {{timezone.name}}
            </option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: what is the name of the formgroup you are using?

Comment: `<form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">`

Answer (score 0):

You can select option using condition:

```
<option [selected]="userDetail.timezone == timezone" [value]="timezone.value" *ngFor="let timezone of timezones.success">`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using reactive form you have to bind the default value of `select` using `setValue` method of the form

```
this.updateForm.controls.timezone.setValue(userDetail.timezone)
```

Put this line in the `ngOnInit()` method so that the value will get binded by default